# how to calculate the height of nested tableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, height

I have one tableView which is full scree in my controller , there is another tableView inside uitableViewcell , both tables are vertical , i can not use section because of my view design, the problem is my inner table can not be scrollable so i should increase height to be able to show all items , the way I'm calculating table height is :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return items.count * 100
}
```

100 is the height of each cell

the problem is when my list goes big tableView shows empty spaces.

Comment: The best would be to change your design.

Comment: You shouldn't use from table view in the table view cell if you don't want to scroll on there, you can use a UIView instead of nested TableView and add another UIView such as the nested TableViewCell on there.

Comment: how should i show 100 items in uiView?

Comment: @Ryan110 - please review [ask]. The screenshots you posted don't seem to relate to your comments such as *"i can not use section because of my view design"* or *"...show 100 items"*. Try to be a little more clear on what your goal is, how you want it to look, etc.

Comment: @Ryan110 - if you want help, you have to tell us / show us what you're trying to do, and why it won't work with multiple sections. Suppose I need to display 100 names... I could embed a 100-row table view in a cell (bad idea)... I could embed 100 labels in a cell (still a bad idea)... I could embed one multi-line label in a cell with all 100 names. I could use multiple sections. I could use a single section, but multiple cell classes. You are saying "*something* isn't working -- how do I get *something* to work." Tough to offer assistance.

Comment: Hi DonMag, thank you been so suportive , I did remove my screen shots because they are privates, acually my design is one fulls screen view with two view(tableView) inside, the inner views(tableViews) has corner Radious and each inner view height must grow up with it's content, and I'm trying to calculating the height of tableView but as content goes with bigger items the height calculating goes wrong too and this is autoLayout problem,this is the problem, so why I don't use sections ? because how can i make cornerRadious for each section ?this is my question now , leave your solution tnx:X

Comment: @Ryan110 - are you trying to get something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rphrR.png ??

Comment: yes yes , two section is okay

Comment: @Ryan110 - you can do this with multiple sections and setting the table view style to **inset grouped** ... then a quick search for `uitableview inset grouped section bordered` finds several ways to add the section border / outline.

Comment: I can make your comment as a correct answer

Comment: make your comment as post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

- use multiple sections
- set table view style to **inset grouped**
- add/draw a border/outline around the section

Searching for `uitableview inset grouped section bordered` finds several different ways to add the border. Likely you can find a method that suits your coding style / needs.